# Swift - Add URL with AttributedString to UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to add a link to my uitextview when I press a button.

So far I have managed to do that, but if I start editing the text in my UITextView it continues as a link.

I have many managed to kind of sort that by adding a range for the attributed text, which works but then If I go back and delete for example the URL(attributedString) the text is now again all an attributed String(link)...

Here's some of my code:

```
  @IBAction func webLink(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Insert Link", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)


        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "URL"
            textField.keyboardType = .URL

        }

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Link name"
            textField.keyboardType = .default
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let insertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Insert", style: .default) { (action) in


            let systemFont = self.Text.font!
            let linkAttributes = [
                NSFontAttributeName : systemFont,
                NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: alertController.textFields![0].text!)!] as [String : Any]

            let myAttributes2 = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: customGreen ]
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(alertController.textFields![1].text!)   ")

            // Set the 'click here' substring to be the link
            attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, 3))

            self.Text.linkTextAttributes = myAttributes2
            self.Text.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: self.Text.selectedRange.location)

            let cursor = NSRange(location: self.Text.selectedRange.location + "\(alertController.textFields![1].text!)   ".characters.count, length: 0)
            self.Text.selectedRange = cursor
            self.Text.font = systemFont

        }

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(insertAction)


        self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
        }


     }
```

Comment: Maybe with setting `typingAttributes` when selection changes?

Comment: @Larme I actually read a post about typingAttributed 5 minutes ago, not sure how it works though, do you think that could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use UITextView delegate function:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {...}
```

In that function you can't override inserting " " (space) character with your attributes.

[About string attributes](https://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/)

### Full example in Swift 3

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textView.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func webLink(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Insert Link", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "URL"
        textField.keyboardType = .URL
    }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Link name"
        textField.keyboardType = .default
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let insertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Insert", style: .default) { (action) in

        if let urlName = alertController.textFields![1].text {

            let systemFont = self.textView.font!
            let linkAttributes = [
                NSFontAttributeName : systemFont,
                NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: alertController.textFields![0].text!)!] as [String : Any]

            let myAttributes2 = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]

            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: urlName)

            // Set the 'click here' substring to be the link
            attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, urlName.characters.count))

            self.textView.linkTextAttributes = myAttributes2
            self.textView.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: self.textView.selectedRange.location)

            let cursor = NSRange(location: self.textView.selectedRange.location + urlName.characters.count, length: 0)
            self.textView.selectedRange = cursor
            self.textView.font = systemFont
        }
    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(insertAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true) {}
}
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if text == " " {
        let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black, NSFontAttributeName: self.textView.font!] as [String : Any]
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
        self.textView.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: range.location)
        let cursor = NSRange(location: self.textView.selectedRange.location+1, length: 0)
        textView.selectedRange = cursor
        return false
    }
    return true
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11201" systemVersion="16A323" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11161"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_40611248" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MAb-bM-rda">
                            <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="webLink:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="lEW-xK-QqL"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NfR-7H-lIY">
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="240" id="oZX-gx-ivA"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <string key="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</string>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        </textView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="MAb-bM-rda" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerY" id="EUe-Ac-j39"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="NfR-7H-lIY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="162" id="LtY-X7-xvc"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="MAb-bM-rda" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="XWA-IA-8Bd"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="MAb-bM-rda" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="NfR-7H-lIY" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="cUB-uR-AvM"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="NfR-7H-lIY" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="MAb-bM-rda" secondAttribute="centerX" id="pyb-a7-lJG"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="textView" destination="NfR-7H-lIY" id="vYj-cp-6P8"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Just tested seems alright, I shall put it in my app and try it out later, Thanks alot +1 for now!

Comment: Right I have tested it out, works good so far but the only problem is, is that it changes all the text font. For example: I have some bold text and italic text in my textview but after insert a link all the text gets set back to the normal system font.. any idea why?

Comment: You can set your attributes in this line: let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: nil)

Comment: It gets reset when i insert the url link, not make a space though

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yes I already added what you just added yesterday, that is the problem... If I have some text in the textView that is already Bold and some text that is italic, After I add the link all the text in the text view (italic and bold) gets set back to normal system font

Comment: I edited the answer 1 hour ago. Also, I add link about string attributes. Read about it

Comment: So I miss typed, I added what you have just added to the edit yesterday to my project, I already added that 1 line of code yesterday

Comment: Did you fixed your problem? Can you mark the question?

Comment: Nope haven't looked into it yet...I'm sure it won't be too hard...will mark it when i figure it out, or if you help me figure it out

Comment: Still haven't figure it out, but accepting your answer as it helped me alot!